# Clustered index dilemma - ID or sort?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a table with two very important fields:

```
id INT identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
identifiersortcode VARCHAR(900)
```

My app *always* sorts and pages search results in the UI based on `identifiersortcode`, but all table joins (and they are legion) are on the `id` field. *(Aside: yes, the sort code really is that long. There's a strong BL reason.)*

Also, due to O/RM use, most SELECT statements are going to pull almost every column.

Currently, the clustered index is on `id`, but I'm wondering if the TOP / ORDER BY portion of most queries would make `identifiersortcode` a more attractive option as the clustered key, even considering all of the table joins going on.

Inserts on the table and changes to the `identifiersortcode` are limited enough that changing my clustered index would be a problem for insert/update operations.

Trying to make the sort code's non-clustered index a covering index (using `INCLUDE`) is not a good option. There are a number of large columns, and some of them have a lot of update activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently, the clustered index is on id, but I'm wondering if the TOP / ORDER BY portion of most queries would make identifiersortcode a more attractive option as the clustered key, even considering all of the table joins going on.

Making `identifiersortcode` a `CLUSTERED KEY` will only help if it is used both in filtering and ordering conditions.

This means that it is chosen a leading table in all your joins and uses `Clustered Index Scan` or `Clustered Index Range Scan` access path.

Otherwise, it will only make the things worse: first, all secondary indexes will be larger in size; second, inserts in non-increasing order will result in page splits which will make them run longer and result in a larger table.

Comment: Alas, that's what I suspected. It's definitely not the leading table in all joins.

Answer (score 4):

Kimberly L. Tripp's [criteria for a clustered index](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx) are that it be:

- Unique
- Narrow
- Static
- Ever Increasing

Based on that, I'd stick with your integer identity `id` column, which satisfies all of the above. Your `identifiersortcode` would fail most, if not all, of those requirements.

Comment: The criticism  I have of this is that it presumes that INSERT/UPDATE Performance is always more important than SELECT. Which its not. For example its pretty silly to take this advice on a lookup table that changes very rarely. Also the article overly worries about diskspace. (the narrow rationale in particular)

Comment: @Conrad - It's not really about disc space. It's about reducing I/O and making efficient use of memory. The reason for `narrow` is that the `CI` is used as the row locator in all `NCI`s adding 900 bytes for each row to all of these could increase their size massively and also depth.

Comment: @Martin these are fair statements but I think a checklist like this without understanding the rationale (which I grant you do probably better than me) is that its really easy to end up with Cago Cult Index design.

Comment: I'm with you, Joe, which is why I already went down the path I did. Just a little second-guessing, since Conrad's points are true--some of the benefits of Tripp's guidelines aren't in play as much in this case. I didn't even think about Marin's point, and that's enough by itself to throw out using a varchar(900) field in the clustered index.

Answer (score 2):

To correctly determine which field will benefit most from the clustered index, you need to do some homework.  The first thing that you should consider is the selectivity of your joins.  If your execution plans filter rows from this table FIRST, then join on the other tables, then you are not really benefiting from having the clustered index on the primary key, and it makes more sense to have it on the sort key.

If however, your joins are selective on other tables (they are filtered, then an index seek is performed to select rows from this table), then you need to compare the performance of the change manually versus the status quo.

Comment: Very good point. Truth is, could be either. These tables are first-class entities in the application, but it's just as likely for a user to search within the table as it is for them to search for some other entity related to some subset of these.

Answer (score 1):

Why, for God's sake, does your identifier sort code need to be 900 characters long? If you really need 900 characters to be distinct for sorting, it should probably be broken up into multiple fields.

Comment: It's the result of taking a string that contains an *arbitrary* number of groupings of text and numbers, all of which have to sort properly. Example: "1-iv.A(2)c(FOOBAR)(1000)(iii)". The position and length of each word varies--e.g., word 2 isn't always roman numerals. This requires removing delimiters, left/right padding each "word" to a fixed length, and some other dark magic for roman numeral detection and sorting. I'm definitely looking into alternatives. It's an interesting business logic issue, but outside the scope of this question.

Comment: That's brutal, man. If your resultset is generally reasonably small, you might consider sorting it in the business layer. You could load the order field into a class that parses it and then (if you're in the .Net world) you could sort them using a custom comparer. At any rate, hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Appart from repeating what Chris B. said, I think you should really stick to your current PK, since - as you said - all joins are on the Id.
I guess you already have indexed the identifiersortcode....
Nevertheless, IF you have performance issues, would reaaly think twice about this @#"%$£ identifiersortcode !-)

Comment: Agreed, I'm looking into alternatives for the sort code, but haven't found one quite yet. Regardless, there will always be a separate sorting column and ID column.